# calling Wcf rest Service in Angular JS with in the function is not working with $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi iam trying to call the Wcf rest service when change the list item in angular JS

here is my sample code

```
 function sample($scope, $http) {

$http({
    url:     'http://localhost/DataFlow.InternalServices/Service.svc/rest/GetClientValues',
   headers: { 'MyCustomHttpHeader': xmlInput }
}).
    success(function (data) {
        var ClientsData = angular.fromJson(eval("(" + data.GetClientValuesResult + ")"))
        $scope.availableClients = ClientsData.ListData;
    });

$scope.selectedClients = [];

$scope.loadEntities = function (selectedItem) {
    sToken = GenerateToken();
    var selClients = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItem.length; i++) {
        selClients = selClients + "," + selectedItem[i].ClientID;
    }
    var selectedClients = selectedItem[0].ClientID;
    xmlInput = "<security_token><token>" + sToken + "</token><drawer_id>0000000000</drawer_id><clients>" + selClients + "</clients></security_token>"
    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost/DataFlow.InternalServices/Service.svc/rest/GetEntityByClient',
        headers: { 'MyCustomHttpHeader': xmlInput }
    }).
    success(function (data) {
        $scope.availableEntities = [];
        var EntityData = angular.fromJson(eval("(" + data.GetEntityListValuesByClientResult + ")"))
        $scope.availableEntities = EntityData.ListData;
    });
    $scope.selectedEntities = [];

};
```

on calling of loadEntites i need to call service again and refresh the items but with the above techinique its always loading previous list only.

how do i reload the latest data.

Comment: First off I would recommend pulling your $http requests into a service - it will help to clarify the code a bit more and then you can see what is potentially going wrong.

Comment: Also i dont understand what the first line is supposed to be $function?

Comment: its normal function only i think its mistyped

Comment: So its the controller then?

Comment: Exactly and i got resolved this issue by passing some dummy parameter because every time when i call the service without parameters its treating as same request as previous and its not hitting the service now i am passing extra parameter to the service by changing value every time Thanks for taking time on this Sten Muchow.